# Grub menu still displayed with 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I wish to hide the grub menu, but with the right settings in `/etc/default/grub`, the grub menu is still displayed at boot. I run `sudo update-grub` after each edited. Bellow my grub file:

```
cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

With the following settings, I still have the menu display while it should not:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Same issue with:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

In fact, I have the same effect that the following:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with dual-boot windows. Ubuntu is the default entry in grub. I edit the file with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` then I run `sudo update-grub` with success. Could you help me to really hide the grub menu please?

Edit:
Following the answer from abu_bua, the issue was solved with add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` here my new grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: @Melebius: No, my ask is different and it's not about timeout but menu always displayed.

Comment: weird. even with this exact config, I see a short countdown in the upper right corner: "2" ... "1" ... "0" before it actually boots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add without space between

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER= true   # WRONG
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true    # correct setting of variable
```

to your grub file and then update your grub by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Good answer, I made a minor edit to make it look like a more authoritative answer (removed "did you try...").

Comment: True. The "os prober" module seems to be forcing timeout = 10, for whatever reason. It comes from `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` here in Ubuntu 22.

Comment: The GRUB_TIMEOUT parameter defines the time waiting in the grub menu before it starts the default distro. I set it to 3s, since I have several distros and it is also very handy if it is necessary to boot the rescue (old) kernel.