# upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 - computer opens to terminal

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

I am running a Lenovo Flex 11, and have been running perfectly with version 18.10. Got notice that 19.4 was available and decided why not? During the process there was apparently a hiccup of some sort and I was told that a partial installation would be done. I admit perfect ignorance in Linux and Terminal. Installation completed, and am using it with a kink.  Upon shutting the lid of the laptop, the computer goes to sleep, and is ordinarily awakened tapping any key. Now, I must force full shutdown, then restart. Computer now starts and displays Terminal screen, showing Gnu Grub 2.02 opening screen with three choices...Ubuntu, advanced options, and system setup. Ubuntu is selected by default and I go with it, to eventual Ubuntu startup and login sequence. Info shows Gnome 3.32.1 and my CPU is an Intel Pentium Silver N 5000.
Am pleased with the way the system works under 19.4, except for the initial Terminal startup business and the requisite full shutdown from sleep before being able to restart and use. Can this installation be corrected or made to be a complete rather than partial installation?

Answer (score 0):

This "initial startup business" is called **GRUB** and it's your bootloader, required to boot Ubuntu. If don't dual boot along with Windows, you can simply hide it or shorten the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value.

Related questions:

- [Grub menu still displayed with 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045656/grub-menu-still-displayed-with-18-04)
- [How to set GRUB timeout to 0 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036091/how-to-set-grub-timeout-to-0-on-ubuntu-18-04)

When there was any kind of interruption during upgrade process and you have any other issues make sure that dpkg process was done fully by runing this in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Also make sure that your Ubuntu is up-to-date by runing:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

When it comes for waking up your PC from sleep mode, there might be a bug in new Ubuntu. Please take your time to report it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I was thinking the problem of waking up the computer could be a bug, but I also thought it might be an artifact of the partial upgrade, so want to be sure of my upgrade first. I am grateful for your patience with me in this matter...am wondering if the "---configure -a" command can be given in the same terminal session as the next two commands you provided in your answer - my own ignorance is complete, as I said. Dziękuję Ci

Comment: Just to be clear: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is for resuming an incomplete upgrade process, if it was somehow interrupted. These two other apt commands are just for standard upgrade. Nie ma za co.

Comment: In using the "update" and then the "full-upgrade" commands, there was no change in the form of v.19.04 installed in my computer. 
...repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386

I have a screen shot of the transaction, but unsure if screen shots are permitted here, so I just copied the phrase which seems instructive to those who understand. I am going to take your suggestion to report what I perceive as a bug. As always I am willing to be wrong.