# GRUB behaviour doesn't react to changes in config

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

I want GRUB to hide and wait 2 seconds to boot straight to Windows 10 unless I hit Esc. I modified /etc/default/grub according to the docs:

```
'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE'
 If this option is unset or set to 'menu', then GRUB will display
 the menu and then wait for the timeout set by 'GRUB_TIMEOUT' to
 expire before booting the default entry.  Pressing a key interrupts
 the timeout.

 If this option is set to 'countdown' or 'hidden', then, before
 displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the timeout set by
 'GRUB_TIMEOUT' to expire.  If <ESC> is pressed during that time, it
 will display the menu and wait for input.  If a hotkey associated
 with a menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu
 entry immediately.  If the timeout expires before either of these
 happens, it will boot the default entry.  In the 'countdown' case,
 it will show a one-line indication of the remaining time.
```

And it's now looking like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="countdown"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="2"
```

Unfortunately, nothing changes and GRUB is still showing after running

> sudo update-grub

I've also tried Grub Customizer and it has successfully changed the order list and the names of the options, but has not worked with the hidding.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 and Windows 10. Secure Boot has been enabled and disabled without any effect.

Anyone could lend a hand?

Thanks in advance, J.

EDIT: I have already seen the answer in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045656/grub-menu-still-displayed-with-18-04) but If I set

> GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

I cannot boot to Windows, given that it isn't recognized by GRUB.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Waiting for 2 seconds might be too short, Test it with 20 seconds. Also you can change the Default settings to 2s.

Comment: It is irrelevant how long it waits, since my goal is to hide it and it is still showing.

Comment: If you are interested in Dual Booting, whereby Grub provides you with a list of currently installed OS, and an option to select which OS you would like to boot into then; Install EasyBCD for Windows to set up a Boot menu: https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/.  You can also remove/uncomment GRUB_TIMEOUT=“2” code to disable the timer. With EasyBCD, I think you can adjust the timer, otherwise you have to select a default OS to boot into.